# Matlab - displaying a background image

Tags: image, matlab, background

I'm trying to find the median values for the R,G & B channels of each pixel for each 10th image in a set of 100, to find the background image. My values all seem correct but when i try to display the background at the end of my code it's always white, please help

```
%// list all the files in some folder
folder = '~/V&R/1/';
filelist = dir(folder);
images = zeros(480,640,3,100);
% images = [];
%// the first two in filelist are . and ..

count = 1;
for i=3:size(filelist,1)

    if filelist(i).isdir ~= true
        fname = filelist(i).name;
        %// if file extension is jpg
        if strcmp( fname(size(fname,2)-3:size(fname,2)) ,'.jpg'  ) == 1
            tmp = imread([folder fname]);
            images(:,:,:,count) = tmp;
            count = count +1;

        end
    end
end


background = zeros(480,640,3);
 for j=1:480
    for i=1:640
        tmpR = zeros(1,10);
        tmpG = zeros(1,10);
        tmpB = zeros(1,10);
        for k=1:10
            tmpR(k) = images(j,i,1,k*10);
            tmpG(k) = images(j,i,2,k*10);
            tmpB(k) = images(j,i,3,k*10);

        end
        background(j,i,1) = floor(median(tmpR));
        background(j,i,2) = floor(median(tmpG));
        background(j,i,3) = floor(median(tmpB));
    end
 end
imshow(background)
```

thanks

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd say try `imagesc(background)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to vectorize your code. Instead of the following block of code:

```
background = zeros(480,640,3);
for j=1:480
  for i=1:640
    tmpR = zeros(1,10);
    tmpG = zeros(1,10);
    tmpB = zeros(1,10);
    for k=1:10
        tmpR(k) = images(j,i,1,k*10);
        tmpG(k) = images(j,i,2,k*10);
        tmpB(k) = images(j,i,3,k*10);

    end
    background(j,i,1) = floor(median(tmpR));
    background(j,i,2) = floor(median(tmpG));
    background(j,i,3) = floor(median(tmpB));
  end
end
```

write:

```
subimages = images(:, :, :, 1:10:end);
background = median(subimages, 4);
```

now as said before, use imshow with the [] option to show your image:

```
imshow(background, []);
```

if you still see a white image, then it's possible that you are dealing with a matrix of double values that are not between [0, 1]. Images in Matlab are usually of class double or single with values between 0 and 1, or of class uint8 or uint16 with values between 0, 255 or 0, 65535 respectively. If your values are between 0 and 255 but class(subimages) returns double or single, do the following before using imshow():

```
subimages = uint8(subimages);
```

Comment: this is equivalent to the following line of code;

    imshow(background, [min(background(:), max(background(:)]);

if both your min(background(:)) and max(background(:)) are zero, then your original images 4D matrix has a problem.

Comment: i got 3 and 210 for the minimum and maximum but still get a white image

Comment: Then you probably have an image that has just a few low value pixels and the rest of the image is all (210, 210, 210) for RGB values. Using imshow(..., []), all those values translate to white and you probably can't detect the darker scattered pixels. Use imtool(subimages, []) and play with the threshold tool to see if you can find any scattered points like that.

Comment: with your edited code i still get the error message i posted for the answer below :S

Comment: Try the last part that I just added to the original post.

Comment: and i can view all the images - they look like this: http://imgur.com/MnTP7 but with the objects moving

Comment: thanks that was it! They were returning doubles i think, works now, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
imshow(background,[])
```

When using [imshow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html), MATLAB needs to set a display range. For single or double grayscale images, the default display range is [0 1]. This means that any value larger than 1 will be represented as white. You can fix this by setting your own display range manually, say

```
imshow(background,[0 100],
```

or you can let MATLAB calculate a new display range by doing

```
imshow(background,[])
```

which is the same as

```
imshow(background,[min(background(:)) max(background(:))])
```

Comment: hi, i tried using the first option and got this error message:
`??? Error using ==> checkDisplayRange at 22
HIGH must be greater than LOW.

Error in ==> imageDisplayValidateParams at 57
common_args.DisplayRange =
checkDisplayRange(common_args.DisplayRange,mfilename);

Error in ==> imageDisplayParseInputs at 79
common_args = imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in ==> imshow at 199
  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in ==> a1 at 44
 imshow(background,[])`

and then tried the other two but till got the same white image result

Comment: what is the minimum and maximum of background?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code as:

```
%# get filenames of all JPG images in some folder
folder = '~/V&R/1/';
filelist = dir( fullfile(folder,'*.jpg') );
filelist = strcat(folder, filesep, {filelist.name});

%# read files, and store as 'double' images in a 4D matrix
images = zeros(480,640,3, numel(filelist), 'double');
for i=1:numel(filelist)
    images(:,:,:,i) = im2double( imread(filelist{i}) );
end

%# estimate background using median
subimages = images(:,:,:,1:10:end);
background = median(subimages, 4);
imshow(background)
```